# Problems In Cassandra ByteOrderedPartitioner in Cluster Environment

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am using cassandra 1.2.15 with ByteOrderedPartitioner in a cluster environment of 4 nodes with 2 replicas. I want to know what are the drawbacks of using the above partitioner in cluster environment? After a long search I found one drawback. I need to know what are the consequences of such drawback?

```
1) Data will not distribute evenly. 
   What type of problem will occur if data are not distributed evenly?
```

Is there is any other drawback with the above partitioner in cluster environment if so, what are the consequences of such drawbacks? Please explain me clearly.

One more question is, Suppose If I go with Murmur3Partitioner the data will distribute evenly. But the order will not be preserved, however this drawback can be overcome with cluster ordering (Second key in the primary keys). Whether my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Cassandra 1.2.15, I have found a doc pertaining to Cassandra 1.2 which illustrates the points behind why using the ByteOrderedPartitioner (BOP) is a bad idea:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePartitionerBOP_c.html

> - **Difficult load balancing** More administrative overhead is required to    load balance the cluster. An ordered partitioner
>     requires    administrators to manually calculate partition ranges
>     (formerly token    ranges) based on their estimates of the row key
>     distribution. In    practice, this requires actively moving node
>     tokens around to    accommodate the actual distribution of data once
>     it is loaded.
> - **Sequential writes can cause hot spots** If your application tends to    write or update a sequential block of rows at a time, then the
>     writes    are not be distributed across the cluster; they all go to
>     one node.    This is frequently a problem for applications dealing
>     with    timestamped data.
> - **Uneven load balancing for multiple tables** If your    application has multiple tables, chances are that those tables have different row keys and different distributions of data. An ordered
>     partitioner that is balanced for one table may cause hot spots and uneven distribution for another table in the same cluster.

For these reasons, the BOP has been identified as a [Cassandra anti-pattern](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html).  Matt Dennis has a [slideshare presentation on Cassandra Anti-Patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/mattdennis), and his slide about the BOP looks like this:

[image: OPP/BOP]

So seriously, do not use the BOP.

"however this drawback can be overcome with cluster ordering (Second key in the primary keys). Whether my understanding is correct?"

Somewhat, yes.  In Cassandra you can dictate the order of your rows (within a partition key) by using a clustering key.  If you wanted to keep track of (for example) station-based weather data, your table definition might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stationreads (
  stationid uuid,
  readingdatetime timestamp,
  temperature double,
  windspeed double,
PRIMARY KEY ((stationid),readingdatetime));
```

With this structure, you could query all of the readings for a particular weather station, and order them by `readingdatetime`.  However, if you queried all of the data (ex: `SELECT * FROM stationreads;`) the results probably will not be in any discernible order.  That's because the total result set will be ordered by the (random) hashed values of the partition key (stationid in this case).  So while "yes" you can order your results in Cassandra, you can only do so within the context of a particular partition key.

Also, there have been many improvements in Cassandra since 1.2.15.  You should definitely consider using a more recent (2.x) version.

Comment: Ya now I got clear understanding about the drawbacks of BOP. Previously I used BOP in a single node, now I am going to move from single node to cluster (4 Nodes with VNodes enabled by replicas of two) with Murmur3Partitioner along with my old data. So one of the thing has to be consider while moving from BOP to Murmur3Partitioner is "Order of keys". So I have to remodel the table schema by considering the clustering key for my order. Other than this, whether I need to consider any other thing while moving from BOP to Murmur3Partitioner ?

Comment: I've never switched partitioners before, but I'm pretty sure that because partitioning strategy affects the layout of the sstable file(s), you'll need to be ready to reload your data.